# AttributeError: type object 'AuthorDetailView' has no attribute 'as_views'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I'm a beginner in python-django coding. Currently I am following this guide and doing the challenging part for the author page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views) but I am facing a issue of AttributeError: type object 'AuthorDetailView' has no attribute 'as_views'.

Below are my codes:
In urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('books/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
    path('book/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
    path('authors/', views.AuthorListView.as_view(), name ='authors'),
    path('authors/<int:pk>', views.AuthorDetailView.as_views(), name='author-detail'),
]
```

In views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .models import Book, Author, BookInstance, Genre

    def index(request):
        """View function for home page of site."""
    
        # Generate counts of some of the main objects
        num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
        num_instances = BookInstance.objects.all().count()
    
        # Available books (status = 'a')
        num_instances_available = BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='a').count()
    
        # The 'all()' is implied by default.
        num_authors = Author.objects.count()
    
        context = {
            'num_books': num_books,
            'num_instances': num_instances,
            'num_instances_available': num_instances_available,
            'num_authors': num_authors,
        }
    
        # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
    
    from django.views import generic
    
    class BookListView(generic.ListView):
        model = Book
        paginate_by = 5
    
    class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Book
    
    class AuthorListView(generic.ListView):
        model = Author
        paginate_by = 5
    
    class AuthorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Author
```

Would appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo mistake.

it's `as_view()` not `as_views()`.

```
path('authors/<int:pk>', views.AuthorDetailView.as_view(), name='author-detail'),
```

try this.

Comment: Manage to solve it. Thanks. But I am having another issue again. The page runs but the author page isnt running
Here's my code for the author-list.html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Author List</h1>

{% if author_list %}
  <ul>

  {% for author in author_list %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}">
      {{ author }} ({{author.date_of_birth}} - {% if author.date_of_death %}{{author.date_of_death}}{% endif %})
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}

 </ul>
{% else %}
  <p>There are no authors registered.</p>
{% endif %}

Comment: please ask new question in stackoverflow and show your error logs as well. @CalvinLin

Comment: Sorry about that. I just posted it